# переход к нужной директории в putty

Tags: bash, ssh, putty

подключаюсь через putty по ssh к серверу, можно ли как то сделать автоматический переход в нужную директорию например /www/mysite/

в winSCP вроде бы как можно указать параметры запуска putty, но у меня не вышло

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: После хоста указать путь через двоеточие не катит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В главном окне Putty, в разделе SSH, есть поле `remote command` для ввода команд, которые будут выполнены на удаленном сервере при успешном подключении. Если впишите туда `cd /www/mysite/` , то после авторизации перейдете в указанную директорию.